# how to write a test class using @remoteAction

Tags: apex, controller, remote-action

```
@RemoteAction
public static void manipulateincentive(string incentiveid)
{   
    List <string> lstinput = new list<string>();
    lstinput=(list<string>)JSON.deserializestrict(incentiveid,list<string>.class);
    system.debug('SerializedString::'+lstinput);
    map<String,String> updatecourseass = new map<String,String>();
    system.debug('Incvalue::'+incentiveid);
    if(lstinput.size()>0)
    {
        for(String sr :lstinput)
        {
            updatecourseass.put(sr.split('@')[1],sr.split('@')[0]);
        }
    }
    system.debug('Maptoinsert::'+updatecourseass);

    /**Updating course assignment with Incentive**/
    List<lmscons__Training_Path_Assignment_Progress__c> lstToupdate=new list<lmscons__Training_Path_Assignment_Progress__c>();
    List<lmscons__Training_Path_Assignment_Progress__c> updatedlist=new list<lmscons__Training_Path_Assignment_Progress__c>();
    //system.debug('IncValue!!::'+ IncValue);
    system.debug('AssignmentsToUpdate::'+updatecourseass.Keyset()); 
    lstToupdate=[Select id,Incentive__c,Incentive_Assigned_Date__c from lmscons__Training_Path_Assignment_Progress__c where id IN :updatecourseass.Keyset() ];
    For(lmscons__Training_Path_Assignment_Progress__c lisin :lstToupdate)
    {
        system.debug('INCID='+updatecourseass.get(lisin.id));
        if(updatecourseass.get(lisin.id)=='None')
        {
            if(lisin.incentive__c!=null)
            {
                lisin.Incentive__c=null;
                lisin.Incentive_Assigned_Date__c=null;
                updatedlist.add(lisin);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lisin.Incentive__c=updatecourseass.get(lisin.id);
            lisin.Incentive_Assigned_Date__c=System.TODAY();
            updatedlist.add(lisin);
        }



    }
    system.debug('UpdatedList::'+updatedlist);
    if(updatedlist.size()>0)
    {
        update updatedlist;
    }
    updatecourseass.clear();

}
```

Comment: Please refer https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Comment: Hi ALi. Welcome to SFSE. I see that its a method (If I ignore the remote action). You can directly call this method in your test class. ClassName.manipulateincentive(Pass an Id here after creating some test Data). Try doing that and post/update the question if you are stuck

Answer (score 1):

You can write test class like below code.

```
Main class:- 

global with sharing class CheckExtension {
    public CheckExtension(CustomCheck controller) {    }
    @RemoteAction
    global static string getRecNumber(String Rec){
        if(Rec==1)
        return 'you Receive one  Record ';
        else
        return 'you Receive Multiple  Records';

    }
}
```

Test class for above class is:-

```
@isTest
private class MyTest{
    static testmethod testRec1(){
        Test.startTest();
        String str = CheckExtension.getRecNumber('1');
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals('you receive one Record';
    }

    static testmethod testRecNot1(){
        Test.startTest();
        String str = CheckExtension.getRecNumber('2');
        Test.stopTest(0;
        System.assertEquals('you receive multiple records');
    }
}
```

For more info go on below link.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods